# ¿Cómo exporto una base de datos hecha en NetBeans con MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Terminé un proyecto en NetBeans que es una interfaz de una base de datos con conexión a MySQL y quisiera poder exportarlo de alguna forma para poder instalarlo en otro computador donde tambien se conecte con la base de datos, además no sé si necesite hacer algo especial ya que el programa está hecho para conectarse a una base de datos local con MySQL.

Tambien me gustaria saber qué sucedería con el conector JDBC y el JDK para poder correr el programa. Es la primera vez que necesito exportar un programa.

-Aplicaciones
MySQL Workbench 8.0
Apache NetBeans IDE 14
Java: 18.0.1.1

Comment: Y que tipo de instalación buscas? Manual? Desatendida? Remota? Qué has intentado?

Comment: En qué plataforma quieres instalar? Con que versión de Java quieres que sea compatible? Quieres tal vez exportarlo a un programa nativo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero será generar el .jar de lo que has programado:

Este extracto está sacado de google, encontrarás muchos vídeos explicativos en youtube por ejemplo.

**1.** Abre NetBeans.

**2.** Abre el menú de “Project Properties” (propiedades de proyecto). ...

**3.** Marca la casilla que dice “Compress JAR file” (comprimir archivo
    JAR). ...

**4.** Confirma el cambio. ...

**5.** Genera tu proyecto. ...

**6.** Ubica el archivo JAR. ...

Para poder ejecutar un .jar, el ordenador necesita tener instalado JAVA, es decir, si le pasas ese .jar a tu vecina, no va a funcionar... Para ello:
https://www.java.com/es/download/

Finalmente click derecho al .jar y abrir con -> Java.

Para el tema de la base de datos, no has dejado claro si lo que haces es simplemente conectarte o crea la estructura de tablas, inserts etcc....

Volviendo al ejemplo de la vecina, cuando ella ejecute la aplicación le dará error porque el .jar intentará conectarse a una base de datos que no existe, además que habría que tener en cuenta A DÓNDE está tu apuntando tu .jar para conectarse .......

Si lo que quieres es algo para "la familia y amigos", ten en tu configuración algo como "localhost..." y ve a sus casas e instala todos los programas para tener mysql, scripts de la base de datos etc (Que se lo montes tú), en caso contrario, tu .jar debería poder leer un archivo externo, en ese archivo se añadirían parámetros de configuración para conectarse a la ruta="x" dependiendo del usuario al que se lo pases, además que dicho usuario debería tener instalado mysql y todo lo que mencioné antes, obviamente si tu .jar se conecta a una Base de datos con usuario/contraseña con ciertas tablas, donde esté apuntando tu .jar, eso deberá existir.

Comment: Entonces tendría que crear la base de datos MySQL en cualquier PC que vaya a instalar el programa, entiendo... Es para un taller de automóviles entonces tengo que pedirles que me presten el computador que usaran para administrar verdad? Muchas gracias